# É possível utilizar o argumento "break" em um "switch" para interromper um loop?

Tags: php, loop, switch

Quando quero interromper um loop de um `for`, `while` ou `foreach` sempre utilizo o `break;` dentro de um `if` com a seguinte estrutura:

```
$teste = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach($teste as $t){
   if($t == 3){
   echo "Terminando loop ao achar o número ".$t;
   break;
   }
   echo $t."<br />";
}
echo "fim de script";
```

Podemos usar o continue:

```
 foreach($teste as $t){
       if($t == 3){
       echo "O ".$t." é meu!";
       continue;
       }
       echo $t."<br />";
    }
    echo "fim de script";
```

No manual, tem assim:

> Note que no PHP o switch é considerado uma estrutura de loop para os
>   propósitos do continue.

Mas, e seu quiser o `switch` ao invés do `if`, e parar a estrutura `foreach` quando uma determinada ocorrência for encontrada?

é possível a utilização do `continue` para alguns propósitos ou o `break` para interromper o loop do `foreach` fazendo-se uso do `switch`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É possível sim.

Segundo a documentação sobre o [`break`](http://php.net/break):

> `break` aceita um argumento numérico opcional que diz a ele quantas
>   estruturas aninhadas ele deverá finalizar.

Documentação sobre o [`continue`](http://php.net/continue):

> `continue` aceita um argumento numérico opcional que diz quantos níves
>   loops aninhados ele deve pular ao final. O valor padrão é 1, indo
>   assim para o final do loop atual.

Exemplo:

```
$teste = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

foreach($teste as $t){
    switch($t){
        case 1:
          echo "Terminando loop ao achar o número 1<br>";
          break(2); // Finaliza o switch e o for
        case 2:
          echo "Terminando loop ao achar o número 2<br>";
          break;
        case 3:
          echo "Terminando loop ao achar o número 3<br>";
          break;
        default:
          echo "Terminando loop, nenhum número foi achado<br>";
    }
}
echo "fim de script";
```

### [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/B1q04T)

Comment: Não sabia que esse `02` dentro do `break` servia para isso!
Obrigado.

Comment: Eu não sabia disto também, só achei desnecessário os parenteses `()`, mas não invalida a resposta. +1